# how to make a html & css clickable progressbar

Tags: html, css, web

How can I make a clickable progress bar like this ([image](http://s6.picofile.com/file/8202543950/all_page.jpg)) ?

I want to choose one part of progress bar when I clicked on that part !

Answer (score 0):

Many implementations of progress trackers,  rely on images for their appearance. Using images obviously works, but it does present some problems.

**Performance**. When a web page includes images, the web browser has to make separate requests to the web server to retrieve those images. Those requests take time, and they can slow down the performance of the page.

**Quality**. Standard resolution images can look terrible on high resolution displays (such as Apple's Retina). There are techniques to adapt images to high resolution displays, but they take time, effort and programming to implement.

**Fluid Layouts**. Fluid layouts require that web content dynamically adapt to the width of the browser window. If the page includes images, it either has to scale the images (which can reduce their quality), crop the image (which modifies the content), or change the relative proportion of image content to text (which may undesirably change the page's look and feel).

Note: standard progress trackers probably aren't appropriate for fully responsive designs that must support small screen devices. If a task has enough steps to warrant a progress tracker, those steps probably aren't going to fit in a standard, horizontally oriented tracker on a small display.

**[Tracking progress reference](http://blog.sathomas.me/post/tracking-progress-in-pure-css)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can work using some input radio, :checked pseudoclass and sibling (~) selector.

You can take a look here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpBExG

The trick is `input[type='radio']:checked ~ .checker`

It's an incomplete example but I've implemented main logic. You should create better UI using images.